# how to animate 10 consecutive elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have 10 `<i>` elements which are child of a `<div>` They all appear as a white circle. 
I like to create an animation via jquery that scales them up by x3 and then back down to original size. That's easy enough on its own but what I'd like to do is:

Have it so one starts to scale then before that finishes (let say a third of the way through its transition or transform) start the next element and so forth.

Once it reaches the end, start it again. A single loop through all of the elements should be 3 seconds.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

[Update] I like to utilize jquery .animate() functionality instead using keyframes and css animation

```css
.spinner {
  background-color: black; /*So you can see the circles*/
}

.spinner i {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}

.spinner i b {
  display: block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px white;
}
```

```html
<div id="spinner" class="spinner">
  <i><b></b></i><!--1-->
  <i><b></b></i><!--2-->
  <i><b></b></i><!--3-->
  <i><b></b></i><!--4-->
  <i><b></b></i><!--5-->
  <i><b></b></i><!--6-->
  <i><b></b></i><!--7-->
  <i><b></b></i><!--8-->
  <i><b></b></i><!--9-->
  <i><b></b></i><!--10-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after. I have documented in the source.

```js
$(".spinner i").each( function(index, element) {
  const delay = 0.3*index; /* Calculate delay for current element */
  $(element).attr("style","animation-delay:"+delay+"s"); /* Apply delay */
  $(element).addClass("anim"); /* Start the animation */
});
```

```css
.spinner {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  /*So you can see the circles*/
}

.spinner i {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}

.spinner i b {
  display: block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px white;
}
/* Class to define the settings for the animation */
.spinner i.anim {
  animation-name: scale;
  animation-duration: 0.3s; /* Total duration / 10 */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Repeat forever */
}
/* Animation of the scale */
@keyframes scale {
    0%, 100%  {transform: scale(1);}
    50%  {transform: scale(3);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spinner" class="spinner">
  <i><b></b></i>
  <!--1-->
  <i><b></b></i>
  <!--2-->
  <i><b></b></i>
  <!--3-->
  <i><b></b></i>
  <!--4-->
  <i><b></b></i>
  <!--5-->
  <i><b></b></i>
  <!--6-->
  <i><b></b></i>
  <!--7-->
  <i><b></b></i>
  <!--8-->
  <i><b></b></i>
  <!--9-->
  <i><b></b></i>
  <!--10-->
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Gerard, looks good, however I wanted to avoid keyframes and css3 animation. Just use jquery possibly with .animate(). I'd still like to keep this post as an answer though

Comment: Okay. Just keep in mind that simple CSS3 animations are usually faster than jQuery animation because they can run on a different thread.